# Gerund before prepositions

Tags: prepositions, gerunds

I read a sentence like this

> Negotiating for dummies

I know that a gerund is after a preposition, so why in this sentence a gerund "**Negotiating**" is before a preposition "**for**"

Thanks for reading

Comment: What do you mean when you say "gerund is after preposition"? Do you have a problem with "talking to", for example? Whatever this rule you're thinking of is, I'm afraid someone hasn't given you the complete picture, or has outright misled you.

Comment: "Negotiating" as used in your sentence is a noun. Prepositions can precede or follow gerunds, like in : *I am tired of negotiating for dummis*.

Comment: @Josh61 Where is that *z* coming from? Does *negotiating* have a *z* in it in Italian or something?

Comment: @DanBron - typos... anyway yes...the italian is "negoziare"

Comment: Foreign languages make the best bitchslaps. XD

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it appears to be based on an uncommon misapprehension of gerunds in prepositional phrases.

Comment: Oh sorry if this question is too stupid, I am learning 
Gerunds and Infinitives topic, so it is my misunderstanding to think that "Gerund must after preposition".

Comment: Please consider also our sister site http://ell.stackexchange.com/  for your questions.

Answer (score 1):

A gerund may follow a preposition -- we say it's the object of the preposition -- because a gerund has usage as a noun.  And you'll find it in other places where nouns are required.

> **Subject**: **Negotiating** is an important skill.
>   **Direct Object**: I hate **negotiating**.
>   **Nominative Complement**: That was some **negotiating**!

But a gerund is also a verb (it's the present participle, the inflected form made by adding *-ing* to the plain form of the verb).  And so it is associated with the syntactic roles that verbs have.  Consider the ***gerund* clause**

> I watched **him *giving* a man money for coffee**.

There's a subject (*him*), a direct object (*money*), an indirect object (*a man*), and an adverbial prepositional phrase of purpose (*for coffee*).  These are all roles associated with verbs.